# show all files in path directory in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i had a problem .... i want to create HTML/javascript file that see all files in this folder ( in same computer ) , and put the the link each one of them .

i couldn't fine any way to do it , need help on this for real

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>


<BODY topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">

<div>The current directory is: <script type="text/javascript">
function disp_current_directory(){
var dirs=window.location.href.split('/'),
cdir=dirs[dirs.length-2];
document.write(cdir + " " + window.location.href);
var dirFiles ;
for( int i = 0 , i > dirs.length , i++)
{ dirFiles[i] = ???  }
var txt = window.location.href - dirs[dirs.length-1] ; 
document.write( "<br/> " + txt );
}
disp_current_directory();
</script></div>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

i don't know what to do .. need help pls

Comment: This shouldn't be possible with just browser-JavaScript even for the local machine.

Comment: did you try to use html5? is it a viable alternative for you?

Answer (score 0):

Because of some security issues, JavaScript is not allowed to have access to client files without the user's explicit authorization. What you are trying to achieve can't be done using JavaScript